# can I retrieve Data as array from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a two table first is simple primary key based table and second table is keyvaluepair for maintaining records.

Now I want to get records from Table in a single object. If they come as comma separate it's good.

Suppose I have table

ID valueID.

When I will run select query I not want a list of rows. I want a single column (in a row) that I can get the information about all valueIds.

Could someone explain me how can I get them in one instead of list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(valueID) FROM table
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

If you need both the `ID` and the `valueID`, you're better off sticking with an array.

Comment: @user1252580 No problem! Since my answer was helpful, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark. :)